# How to display data in row wise but not in grid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want to display data like below:

```
Title:
_______________________________

description:
posted date:              Button:Apply Job


Title:
_______________________________

description:
posted date:              Button:Apply Job
```

now  have to show data like this which is fetch from database.I don't want to shoe in gridview.I want to print  more than 5 Title like this way.

Please write code how can i do it using repeater?

Comment: Do you not want to use a repeater either?  http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

You can use it to specify the markup exactly as you did above.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a GridView, you might consider a repeater. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx